# Piping, sorting then counting

Tags: linux

I have this task on hand.

**Finish this task using a combined command (a.k.a. piping) using four individual commands. Task: Find all lines containing the keyword "wonderful" from file "day.txt" and sort the lines alphabetically. Pick the first fifteen of the sorted lines and count how many characters there are in the fifteen lines.**

I know the first command should be `grep "wonderful" day.txt` but then I can't figure out what to do afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would do it.

```
grep "wonderful" day.txt | sort | head -15 | wc -c
```

**References:**

- [sort](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html)
- [head](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/head.1.html)
- [wc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wc.1.html)
- [Piping in linux](https://opensource.com/article/18/8/introduction-pipes-linux)